# Data Only from One Server to Another in Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

I see that there are solutions for copying tables from one Postgres SQL server to another.  But I need to transfer ONLY DATA from one server to another.  I noticed the following command:

pg_dump -C -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname

But I do not want to copy anything else other than data.  How can I do that?

Another question. I have multiple tables on Server A.  If I want to copy Data from all tables on Server A to Server B, how can I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy only the data with `pg_dump`, you can use the `-a` flag (or the long form would be `--data-only`):

```
pg_dump -C --data-only -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname
```

Comment: Thank you!  Will that copy data from all tables?  If I want to deselect a table, do we have that option?  For example, if there are 3 tables: tab1, tab2, tab3, can I deselect tab2?  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: yes, you can use `--exclude-table` or the `-T` option.  You can find more information about `pg_dump` here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html